# php web mail application

Tags: php, function, email

I am developing a web application to handle an email list, and I would like to know how to set it up to send emails when the application is in the localhost. I am using `mail()` function, but I am getting a  `failed to connect to the server` error. I am using PHP and Apache. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix this problem? Try and post your source code for us to have a better understanding of your problem. And to answer your question: Your ISP might have blocked port 25 to prevent spam. Try to upload the script online and see if it works.

Comment: I am trying to use PHPMailer now and I am getting the following error: could not execute:/usr/sbin/sendmail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can send via smtp.
here is phpmailer, a good opensource library for sending emails using php:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/

Comment: I downloaded the PHPMailer and used it without succedd. Now I am having this error message. Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail